# Replacing Open File Dialog in Excel XP with a COM Add-in

Tags: com, ms-office, excel-addins

I am working on a C# add-in for Excel XP for which I need to handle file open and save events with my own dialogs. I managed to do this for save by (basically) handing the WorkbookBeforeSave event on the Excel Application object and cancelling the default behaviour. There is a WorkbookOpen event, but it is fired after a document has been opened, not when the user clicks the Open button or presses Ctrl-O.

Here is a similar question, though the solution is for later versions of office and won't work for me: [Replacing Word's Open File Dialog in a COM Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395434/replacing-words-open-file-dialog-in-a-com-add-in)

I cannot simply customise the normal File Open dialog - I need to replace it entirely. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One somewhat hacky way would be to sink the WindowActivate event from Excel's com interface (dispID 0x614 for excel10).  Then keep track of the last hwnd and watch for when it changes & if it is the excel doc window (I think you can use spy++ to find out the excel window names)